# Generate texture from equation as a function of time

Tags: python, blender

I want to generate the texture (only color) of a mesh object in blender dynamically, such that the texture depends on time (or frame) in a animation. For example:

```
color(x,y,t) = cos(x+t)*sin(y+t)
```

I already found the video texture module in the API ([bge.texture](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68a_release/bge.texture.html)) but it is part of the blender game engine. As far as I know this can not be used to render animations.

Answer (score 0):

By right-clicking on a colour swatch you have an option to Add Driver, you can then use python expressions to calculate the value to use. Drivers resemble keyframes but the values are calculated instead of fixed.

Once you have added the driver you use the graph editor to adjust it, in the graph editor header is a menu to chose between f-Curve Editor and Drivers. To see available functions you can use the python console Autocomplete to list them, you also have the option of adding your own functions to the namespace. You can also define variables that can extract values from other objects for you to use in your expressions.

[image]